# How do I sort data from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, plot

I have a test file with the following format:

```
256   8   8   8 0.0000000E+00    0 X Y Z U P                      NELT,NX,NY,N
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000    
0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  3.000000E-01  0.000000E+00  3.409659E-01
5.036753E-02  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  1.505282E-01  5.081596E-02  1.505282E-01  4.801647E-01
1.603390E-01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  4.626809E-01 -4.185359E-01  4.626809E-01  6.966100E-01
3.105075E-01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  8.025292E-01 -6.998333E-01  8.025292E-01  8.214685E-01
```

This continues to approximately ~130,000 lines but the format is simple. I need to find a way to process this data such that I ignore the first 44 lines and then the data following this is "0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  3.000000E-01  0.000000E+00  3.409659E-01" corresponding to "x-coordinate y-coordinate z-coordinate x-velocity y-velocity z-velocity pressure" for a fluid flow simulation I have done.

How can I process this so I group together the "x-coordinate y-coordinate z-coordinate x-velocity y-velocity z-velocity pressure" values to create various plots (such as x velocity vs x-coordinate etc.) ?

I've tried removing the first 44 lines which seemed to work relatively successfully however grouping the following useful data into their corresponding data sets proved unsuccessful.

Comment: Could you try to import it into Excel or Open/LibreOffice Calc, then exporting from there into a regular file format ? (typically CSV) It would simplify your process very much.

Comment: Practically speaking no because I have thousands of these files and doing it manually would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do it in two steps : first clean the file and store it somewhere, then read back from the clean files and do what you want with it.

I chose CSV as the "clean" file format because it is plain and simple, but you can choose other formats.

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path


COUNT_OF_GARBAGE_LINES = 43


def clean_and_truncate_file(infile_path: Path) -> Path:
    # create file named identically in the same directory
    outfile_path = infile_path.parent / (infile_path.stem + "_clean.csv")

    with open(infile_path, "rt") as in_file, open(outfile_path, "wt") as out_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        # now we have both files ready

        # read the first line
        first_line = in_file.readline()
        assert first_line != "", repr(first_line)  # EOF ?
        # TODO: do something if you want with the first line read
        # write the CSV header
        header = ["x-coordinate", "y-coordinate", "z-coordinate", "x-velocity", "y-velocity", "z-velocity", "pressure"]
        csv_writer.writerow(header)

        # now skip the "garbage" lines
        for _ in range(COUNT_OF_GARBAGE_LINES):
            garbage_line = in_file.readline()
            assert garbage_line.startswith("0.000     "), repr(garbage_line)  # maybe not so garbage ?

        # then copy the remaining lines
        for data_line in in_file.readlines():
            if data_line.strip() == "":
                continue  # empty line
            # parse it into separate values
            row_data = tuple(value.strip() for value in data_line.split() if value.strip())
            assert len(row_data) == len(header), repr(data_line)  # not the expected number of values ?
            # then write it in CSV
            csv_writer.writerow(row_data)

        # we have hit the EOF, everything should be fine
    # files closed
    print(f"OK: {infile_path!s} -> {outfile_path!s}")
    return outfile_path


filename = "so74691674.txt"
clean_file_path = clean_and_truncate_file(Path(filename))
# now it is easy to work with the data !
with open(clean_file_path, "rt", newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)  # skip the first line (header)
    for line in csv_reader:
        data = [float(value) for value in line]  # converting data into the appropriate type
        print(data)
```

produces the file `so74691674_clean.csv` :

```
x-coordinate,y-coordinate,z-coordinate,x-velocity,y-velocity,z-velocity,pressure
0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,3.000000E-01,0.000000E+00,3.409659E-01
5.036753E-02,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,1.505282E-01,5.081596E-02,1.505282E-01,4.801647E-01
1.603390E-01,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,4.626809E-01,-4.185359E-01,4.626809E-01,6.966100E-01
3.105075E-01,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,8.025292E-01,-6.998333E-01,8.025292E-01,8.214685E-01
```

and the output :

```
OK: so74691674.txt -> so74691674_clean.csv
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.3409659]
[0.05036753, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1505282, 0.05081596, 0.1505282, 0.4801647]
[0.160339, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4626809, -0.4185359, 0.4626809, 0.69661]
[0.3105075, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8025292, -0.6998333, 0.8025292, 0.8214685]
```